# How to verify recaptcha in server call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, recaptcha

**SITUATION:**

I used to check my recaptcha with a simple form submit with POST to "/login".

I need to change my implementation for security reasons and would like to do something like:

1) Jquery form submit.

2) Make call to server to call verify recaptcha on the server.

3) Receive response without reloading page.

4) Accept login request or not based on response.

---

**QUESTION:**

It looks like I could make an AJAX request ? But I don't know how.

---

**CLIENT CODE:**

```
<div class ="containerMargins">
        <h1 class = "authTitle">Login</h1>
        <form id="loginForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="loginEmail" placeholder="You can't forget it :)" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="loginPassword" placeholder="We hope you didn't forget it ^^" required minlength="12">
          </div>
          <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcRrxMUAAAAANx-AXSdRLAo4Pyqfqg-1vuPSJ5c"></div>
          <button class="btn btn-default" id="loginButton">Submit</button> <span class="userLinks">
          <a class="logLinks" href="/users/register">Register</a><a href="/users/password">Password?</a></span>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>

<% include ../partials/indexScripts %>

<script>

$("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); 
    var email = $("#loginEmail").val();
    var password = $("#loginPassword").val();

    // WOULD LIKE TO MAKE SERVER CALL HERE TO CHECK RECAPTCHA BUT I DONT KNOW HOW

    $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "users/register",
        data: $this.serialize()
    }).done(function(data) {

    if (successfulRecaptcha) {
          firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password ).then( authData => {
    }
    else {
         console.log("You are a robot!");
    }
```

---

**SERVER CODE:**

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    verifyRecaptcha(req.body["g-recaptcha-response"], function(success) {
        if (success) {

        } else {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is that NodeJS on the server? you did not specify

Comment: @DannyZB yes. It is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution :

FRONT END:

```
$this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login",
        data: $this.serialize()
    }).done(function(data) {

        if (data == true) {
```

BACKEND:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    verifyRecaptcha(req.body["g-recaptcha-response"], function(success) {
        if (success) {
            res.send(true);
        } else {
            res.send(false);
        }
    });
});
```